# jQuery blur is not firing on textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, blur

I need to set two dropdown to index = 0 when some text on `txtLoan` box and after lost focus of it.

jQuery 2.0 is not firing this blur event. how to handle this?

`$(function () {` is working fine. I have tabs code in that.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%=txtLoan.ClientID %>').blur(function () {
        alert("HI");
        var inp = $('#<%=txtLoan.ClientID %>');
            if (inp.val() != "") {
                alert("Hi");
                $('#<%=ddlSec.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
            $('#<%=ddlSample.ClientID%>').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
        }
    });
    $(function () {
              ///some code
    });

  </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/maveh/1/

Comment: It must work, is txtLoan correct? Can you provide your aspx code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ItsMeSri/maveh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Put the not working code inside [`$(function () {`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Problem

Element is not present at the time you are attaching the event,

Comment: @James123 make a fiddle .

Comment: @James123 Check it's working http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/maveh/2/ .I just removed your script tags .AS fiddle creates script tags by itself .

Comment: i dont understand why this code not working my page. these controls in jQuery tab

Comment: @James123 is your webpage online ?